# Invalid date issue

Tags: php, date-formatting

I am trying to validate a date in PHP but I am getting an "Invalid date format" error even though I supplied the correct date format. My PHP version is 5.3.8.

Here is my code, please let me know what you think:

```
try
{   
    $validDate = new DateTime("2/2/2011");
    echo "valid format";
}
catch(Exception $e) 
{   
    echo "Date Incident Occurred: Invalid Date format!";
}
```

Comment: Well, if you'd supplied the correct format then you wouldn't be having this problem. Look at the documentation for the `DateTime` constructor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php, that's a perfectly valid format.

Comment: You can use `strtotime` to parse date and make `DateTime` object from it.

Comment: Coulld you please let me know how to validate the date? The above code was working with 5.2 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried inspecting the exception? It's trying very hard to tell you what happened. That's its entire reason for existence. If you really are supplying a valid date, I will bet the exception is telling you something like this:

> 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
>   or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for
>   'EST/-5.0/no DST' instead'

Comment: I'd wager a packet of [HobNobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HobNob) that this is the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $validDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("2/2/2011"));
```

Comment: That won't generate a DateTime object.